# SFML UdpSockets not sending/receiving without error?

Tags: c++, c++11, networking, udp, sfml

I am working on a primitive multiplayer battleship game for my CS class. I am able to get it running and send out information over LAN. To test whether this communication is working, I created a loop with a listener function that will stop when the packet is verified to have been received from the other computer's listen thread.

When I do this, it seems to send the packet, but the loop keeps running forever without any errors and without receiving confirmation that the packets were received by the other computer. Do you have any idea what might be happening?

```
//SFML headers
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
//standard headers
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <exception>


std::atomic_bool running;
unsigned short port;

//Functions for threading

void startListen(sf::UdpSocket *sock, std::atomic_bool *r, sf::IpAddress *ip)
{
    std::cout<<"Listener started"<<std::endl;
    while(*r == true)
    {
        sf::sleep(sf::microseconds(50));
        std::cout<<"Wait done"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<std::to_string(port)<<" port from the listen thread."<<std::endl;
        sf::IpAddress sender;
        sf::Packet p;
        std::cout<<"tryna receive packet"<<std::endl;
        if (sock->receive(p, sender, port) != sf::Socket::Done)
        {
            std::cout<<"Attempt at packet retrieval but packet retrieval failed! Error code 23./nPlease contact developer at mldevelopingstudios@gmail.com to report this failure."<<std::endl;
        }
        std::cout<<"Packet received!"<<std::endl;
        std::string type;
        p >> type;
        std::cout<<"packet recieved, type: "<<type<<std::endl;
    }
}


int main()
{
    port = 4343;

    sf::UdpSocket sock;
    sf::UdpSocket recSock;
    if (recSock.bind(port) != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        std::cout<<"Whoops we crashed!!!!!!!!!!";
        return 0;
    }
    //sock.unbind();

    std::string ip;
    sf::IpAddress IP1 = sf::IpAddress::getLocalAddress();
    sf::String ip11 = IP1.toString();
    std::cout<<"You LAN IP is: "<<ip11.toAnsiString()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Please enter the target IP address of the computer you'd like to play with."<<std::endl;
    std::string iiii;
    std::cin>>iiii;
    sf::String o(iiii);
    ip = o;
    sf::IpAddress IP(ip);

    std::thread listen(startListen, &recSock, &running, &IP);
    listen.detach();

    std::cout<<"Connection check"<<std::endl;
    running = true;

    std::string name;
    std::cout<<"Name? "<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>name;

    while(running == true)
    {
        std::string mess = name;
        sf::Packet packk;
        std::string temp;
        std::cout<<"Message: "<<std::endl;
        std::cin>>temp;
        if(temp == "!!STOP!!")
        {
            running = false;
        }
        else
        {
            mess = mess+ ": "+ temp;
            packk<<mess;
            if(sock.send(packk, IP, port)!= sf::Socket::Done)
            {
                std::cout<<"Sending error in test loop!!!!"<<std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    recSock.unbind();
    return 0;
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated,
thank you and have a nice day.

EDIT: New code is the "minimalist code" and still no errors but nothing is received on either end.

EDIT: Added code to show whats happening

```
//SFML headers
#include <SFML/Network.hpp>
//standard headers
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <algorithm>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <exception>


std::atomic_bool running;
unsigned short port;

//Functions for threading

void startListen(sf::UdpSocket *sock, std::atomic_bool *r, sf::IpAddress *ip)
{
    std::cout<<"Listener started"<<std::endl;
    while(*r == true)
    {
        unsigned short por = 4343;
        sock->setBlocking(false);
        std::cout<<std::to_string(por)<<" port from the listen thread."<<std::endl;
        sf::IpAddress sender;
        sf::Packet p;
        std::cout<<"tryna receive packet"<<std::endl;
        sf::Socket::Status stat = sock->receive(p, sender, por);
        switch(stat)
        {
            case(sf::Socket::Done):
            {
                std::cout<<"Packet receiving completed!"<<std::endl;
                std::cout<<"Packet received!"<<std::endl;
                std::string type;
                p >> type;
                std::cout<<"packet recieved, type: "<<type<<std::endl;
                break;
            }
            case(sf::Socket::NotReady):
                std::cout<<"Socket not ready to received!"<<std::endl;
                break;
            case(sf::Socket::Partial):
                std::cout<<"socket Kinda received?"<<std::endl;
                break;
            case(sf::Socket::Disconnected):
                std::cout<<"Socket disconnected!"<<std::endl;
                break;
            case(sf::Socket::Error):
                std::cout<<"Errorrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr"<<std::endl;
                break;
            default:
                std::cout<<"Oh noooooo"<<std::endl;
                break;
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    port = 4343;

    sf::UdpSocket sock;
    sf::UdpSocket recSock;
    if (recSock.bind(port) != sf::Socket::Done)
    {
        std::cout<<"Whoops we crashed!!!!!!!!!!";
        return 0;
    }
    std::string ip;
    sf::IpAddress IP1 = sf::IpAddress::getLocalAddress();
    sf::String ip11 = IP1.toString();
    std::cout<<"You LAN IP is: "<<ip11.toAnsiString()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Please enter the target IP address of the computer you'd like to play with."<<std::endl;
    std::string iiii;
    std::cin>>iiii;
    sf::String o(iiii);
    ip = o;
    sf::IpAddress IP(ip);

    std::thread listen(startListen, &recSock, &running, &IP);
    listen.detach();

    std::cout<<"Connection check"<<std::endl;
    running = true;

    std::string name;
    std::cout<<"Name? "<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>name;

    while(running == true)
    {
        std::string mess = name;
        sf::Packet packk;
        std::string temp;
        std::cout<<"Message: "<<std::endl;
        std::cin>>temp;
        if(temp == "!!STOP!!")
        {
            running = false;
        }
        else
        {
            mess = mess+ ": "+ temp;
            packk<<mess;
            sf::Socket::Status stat = sock.send(packk, IP, port);
            switch(stat)
            {
                case(sf::Socket::Done):
                    std::cout<<"Packet Sending completed!"<<std::endl;
                    break;

                case(sf::Socket::NotReady):
                    std::cout<<"Socket not ready to send!"<<std::endl;
                    break;
                case(sf::Socket::Partial):
                    std::cout<<"socket Kinda sent?"<<std::endl;
                    break;
                case(sf::Socket::Disconnected):
                    std::cout<<"Socket disconnected!"<<std::endl;
                    break;
                case(sf::Socket::Error):
                    std::cout<<"Errorrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr"<<std::endl;
                    break;
                default:
                    std::cout<<"Oh noooooo"<<std::endl;
            }
        }
    }

    recSock.unbind();
    return 0;
}
```

The socket on the receiving end is constantly reporting sf::Socket::NotReady
The sending reports sf::Socket::Done
Nothing is received on either end, when blocking is set to true or false

Comment: The code you posted is very long. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somehow solved the problem through repetitive testing. I believe my error came from the operator overloads to load my classes into the packet. Or it was my IP entry. One of the two, fixed it. Sadly I did not document the fix though I am sure that was one of the two issues.